# Get SharePoint group's MembershipGroupId in JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-server, client-object-model

I am trying to get MembershipId of SharePointGroup using GroupName.

I can reach to the group using below but unable to get the member function or property which will give me Id for that group.

SP.ClientContext.get_Current().get_web().get_siteGroups().getByName("GroupName")

This gives me object but I am looking for getting the Id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SP.GroupCollection.getByName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246409(v=office.15).aspx) returns [SP.Group object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245927(v=office.15).aspx), where`SP.Group.get_id` property corresponds to `membershipGroupId`.

Example:

```
var groupName = "Approvers";

var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var group = ctx.get_web().get_siteGroups().getByName(groupName);
ctx.load(group);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
  function() {
      var membershipGroupId = group.get_id();
      console.log(membershipGroupId);
  },
  function(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message());
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim. I will try above code looks promising. But isn't it possible to get by adding get_id() directly to script SP.ClientContext.get_Current().get_web().get_siteGroups().getByName("GroupName").get_id()

Comment: Nope, group object have to be requested first due to async nature of JSOM

Comment: is it psossible to get the groups from the site collection using the Group name  "Starts With " or "Contains"  keyword?